# Identify the certificate that is included in a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have created and installed a provisioning profile. However, I appear to have multiple certificates of the same type as that used with the profile, installed in my Keychain. I am trying to identify the certificate included in the provisioning profile so that I can delete the others. The certificates are identically named, so that doesn't help and I can't see the certificate serial number in the profile. I can take a guess using the certificate expiry date, but I'd like to be sure.

How do I identify the correct certificate?

Answer (score -1):

Delete all of the provisioning profiles and then run you app again. Xcode will create another profile once you have typed in your password.

Another thing you can do is take a look at the date the profile was created. The delete the older ones and keep the newer ones